# GoCardless Event Won't Deserialise

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, gocardless

I'm trying to implement the new GoCardless API, but I'm having trouble handling webhooks.

i've read the response to a string, by doing:

```
Stream req = Request.InputStream;
req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

string requestContent = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
```

This gives me a json response as follows:

```
"{\"events\":[{\"id\":\"EV000SDG4B5WRP\",\"created_at\":\"2017-07-31T08:17:16.202Z\",\"resource_type\":\"mandates\",\"action\":\"cancelled\",\"links\":{\"mandate\":\"MD0002010AE1MV\"},\"details\":{\"origin\":\"api\",\"cause\":\"bank_account_closed\",\"description\":\"The customer's account was disabled at your request.\"},\"metadata\":{}}]}"
```

According to the docs, I should then be able to do

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoCardless.Resources.Event>(requestContent);
```

However, this always gives me a blank object, with all properties set to null.

The source code to the Event class can be found here: https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-dotnet/blob/master/GoCardless/Resources/Event.cs

Why will this not deserialize to the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure that JSON is an array of events. So first you need a root object:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<GoCardless.Resources.Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Now deserialise into that type:

```
var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(requestContent);
```

Comment: I wondered that too, but when I try that I get an error: `"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GoCardless.Resources.Event]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: Oops, my error - you need a root object - have edited.

Comment: yep - that works! If only they'd kept it simple and made a separate call for each event.

Comment: Surely simple would be to have a single call that could return any number of events, so, like this? :)